# drupal calling a node_view gives the wrong data

Tags: drupal, load, drupal-views

I have a block created by a view that loads the teaser of the latest page created by using the Row style of Node teaser.

I'm displaying this block on a custom content type page. The block is displaying the node body content of the main node instead of showing the node from the view that I created.
I did some Googling and it seems that it may have something to do with calling node_load or node_view multiple times and maybe running PHP5.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same result when viewing the block alongside other content types?

Comment: does the block take an argument at all (blocks technically can't have arguments)?

Comment: No arguments taken, just displaying a teaser of the last Page type published. It looks fine in the preview in the View.
The same happens when trying to display the block on another content type's page.